# GAM residuals , GAM check

Tags: regression, residuals, nonlinear-regression, generalized-additive-model

I am doing my GAM regression analysis in `R` and by using the `gam.check()` function from the `mgcv` package I got these results and I was wondering if I can follow the outputs of my model or not? [image: Response and fitted Values] [image: Deviance residuals] [image: Histogram of residuals] [image: residual and linear predictor]

Comment: Do you mean "trust the outputs of your model"? Diagnostic plots for glm models such as yours can be difficult to be interpret. You should look into using the DHARMa package, which produces more easily interpretable diagnostic plots. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267461/how-do-i-get-the-residuals-for-a-glm-with-a-binary-response-variable-using-r, for example.

Comment: Is it also appilicable for GAM ?

Comment: Yes, the package manual says that DHARMa accomodates gam models fitted with the mgcv package.

Comment: If you added `rep = 100` or some such number to the `gam.check()` call you'd get intervals on the QQ plot, which work simulating new data from the model and residualising them to form the reference quantiles. As this is done `rep` times we can form crude intervals by taking the upper and lower quantiles of the simulated values for each observation to form a reference band.

Comment: Thank you for your help , DHARMa package was super useful ; and your method as well